# How to fetch a particular key value from a json datatype from a table in postgres using query

Tags: jquery, json, postgresql, key, psql

I have a column(display_settings) of datatype json in my table(user_profile). And the values stored will be in this formate.

```
{"privacy":{"goals":"public","groups":"public","friends":"public","gVisibility":1,"cVisibility":1,"fVisibility":1},"name":"default","diary":{"font":{"family":"Arial","size":"14","color":"#000000","weight":"normal","bgcolor":"#ffffff","style":"normal","decoration":"none"}}}
```

I want to get only the key value of

> privacy.fVisibility

using query in postgress. Please suggest me a way to get a particular key value from a json. The json value also will be obtained from another select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT privacy->'fVisibiity'AS fVisibility FROM table_name;
```